# Scheme/Racket Operations in Binary tree (+, -, *, /)

Tags: scheme, racket

how can I make a function that operates 2 binary trees? for example if the operation is “+”, the n-esim number of every node of the resultant tree will be the sum of the n-esim number of the 1st tree with the n-esim number of the 2nd tree, considering the  same structure for each node (if the node is a list the sum would be a list, if the node is number the result would be a number, etc).

Here is an example:

```
(operate "+" ’((1 2)((2 3) null null) null) ’((0 2)((1 4) null null) null))
```

the return should be:

```
’((1 4) ((1 7) null null) null)
```

Note: the representation is `(Father (leftSon)(rightSon))`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few fishy things about your question:

- the operation `+` should not be a string
- the way you express your list, *null* is actually the *symbol* null and not the empty list
- your elements are not consistently represented as (father leftSon rightSon)
- 2 + 3 is 5 so the result you give seems incorrect

but assuming this is really what you want, it's a simple list traversal:

```
(define (operate fun sxp1 sxp2)
  (cond
    ((null? sxp1) sxp1)     ; the real empty list
    ((eq? 'null sxp1) sxp1) ; the symbol null
    ((pair? sxp1) (cons (operate fun (car sxp1) (car sxp2))
                        (operate fun (cdr sxp1) (cdr sxp2))))
    (else (fun sxp1 sxp2)))) ; atom => apply fun to elements
```

Testing:

```
> (operate + '((1 2) ((2 3) null null) null) '((0 2) ((1 4) null null) null))
'((1 4) ((3 7) null null) null)
```